# How to check if the mouse is clicked in a certain area (pygame)

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a program in pygame which will print something if the mouse is pressed in a certain area. I have tried using the mouse.get_pos and mouse.get_pressed but I am not sure if I am using them correctly. Here is my code

```
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            mpress = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if mpos[0] >= 400 and mpos[1] <= 600 and mpress == True:
                print "Switching Tab"
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?  Maybe you should implement some debug code to output mpos[0] and mpos[1] and mpress to screen or console so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to define the area, check if the mouse button was pressed in the event loop and use the `collidepoint` method of the `area` rect to see if it collides with the `event.pos` (alternatively `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`).

```
import sys
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    # A pygame.Rect to define the area.
    area = pg.Rect(100, 150, 200, 124)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:  # Left mouse button.
                    # Check if the rect collides with the mouse pos.
                    if area.collidepoint(event.pos):
                        print('Area clicked.')

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        pg.draw.rect(screen, (100, 200, 70), area)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

in my games I used `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` to check mouse press:

```
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        (x, y)= pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if x >= 400 and y <= 600 and event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print "Switching Tab"
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it may help you. `pygame.mouse.get_pressed` returns `{False,False,False}`. Its first element becomes True if we do right click on mouse, and its third element becomes True if we do left click on mouse.

```
while True:
DISPLAYSURF.fill(BLACK)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        mpos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mpress = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if mpos[0] >= 400 and mpos[1] <= 600 and mpress[0] == True:#if you want user to do right click on mouse
            print "Switching Tab"
```